# JavaFX: Text in button not centered when using custom font

Tags: java, javafx

I want to use the "[Another Danger](https://fontsme.com/another-danger.font)" font in my project. However JavaFX isn't quite liking it. Labels and buttons seem to estimate the height of the letters wrong and take a completely wrong size.

I wrote a simple example illustrating the problem:

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Button button = new Button("Test");
    Scene scene = new Scene(button, 320, 240);
    button.setFont(Font.loadFont(HelloApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/AnotherDanger-Demo.otf"), 30));
    stage.setTitle("Hello!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

The text in the button is clearly not centered. However, when I remove the custom font everything works perfectly. Is  this a problem with the font? And if so is there any way to fix this?

I'd be very thankful for any help here.

EDIT: Here are screeshots as requested:

With the font:

[image]

Without the font:

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your application?

Comment: Yeah for sure. I added two screenshots explaining my problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that font is making excessive use of the descent, which it making the glyphs essentially occupy space primarily in the bottom of the space allocated to each of them. Try experimenting with the alignment of the button, e.g. set it to `BASELINE_CENTER` or `BOTTOM_CENTER`

Comment: thanks for the screenshots :) agree with @James_D - it's probably the excentric font not fx that's messing up

Comment: Alright. We will go with a different font then. Thanks for your input!